# Horizontal Website with Vertical Columns

Tags: css

I'm trying to create this layout in css:

[image]

Several blogs (e.g. http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/) mentioned that the best way to do this is using the table layout. And it works actually, but the problem is i cant scroll the individual vertical panels, they always occupy their actual content. I tried to set a height explicitly for each but it's always ignored.

**The CSS**:

```
main {

    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;

    .cycle-progress{
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .cycle-progress > div{
        display: table-cell;
        width: 600px;
        height: 1000px;
        h1{
            background-color: #ffde17;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

    }

    .cycle-progress > div:nth-child(even){
        background-color: white;
    }

}
```

**The HTML**

```
<main>

    <div class="cycle-progress">
        <!--ng-init="timeline =  $('.timeline').timeline()" -->
        <div ng-repeat="pc in production_cycles" ng-controller="ProductionCycleCtrl" data-pcid="{{pc.id}}">
            <h1 class="text-center m-t-none">{{pc.name}}</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 padder-lg">
                    <img src="/src/img/pc-init.svg" style="width: 200px" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">

                    <div timeline class="timeline"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div style="height: 1000px; background-color: red"></div>-->
        </div>  
    </div>


</main>
```

Comment: show what you're trying to do

Comment: @NeilMartin added my code

Comment: some funny possibilities with column-size : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwOEWW

Comment: @GCyrillus exactly what i need, but once i added two containing divs(as i have in my code) it messed up http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEavwz

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam it's a matter of inheritance from height's value : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emeLKX   ### html, body, main ,.ng-scope,.root{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

Comment: @GCyrillus very close, but Chrome need a redraw each time i change any of the content in the columns https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uj6PLWSE124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A flexbox sized to occupy as much horizontal space as necessary should work:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100vw;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
}

.column {
  max-height: 100%
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

For browsers that don't support flexboxes styling the columns as inline-blocks setting their parents to no-wrap might work too.

Comment: but the columns would only occupy the view port, what if i want a fixed width columns that would extend beyond the viewport

Comment: the `fit-content` will make them spill out of the viewport

Comment: got it working, but a note from this article http://red-team-design.com/horizontal-centering-using-css-fit-content-value/ 'fit-content value is kinda experimental and it's not a final recommendation. It's available in W3C Editor's Draft and that means that specs might change in the future.'

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice of setting explicit height(As I see in your post), then the solution is simple.

Wrap everything inside the table cell with a `div` and set `height` and `overflow`.

#### The HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="pc in production_cycles" ng-controller="ProductionCycleCtrl" data-pcid="{{pc.id}}">
    <div class="wrapper-element">
        <h1 class="text-center m-t-none">{{pc.name}}</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <!--more content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### The CSS:

```
.cycle-progress > div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 600px;
  > .wrapper-element {
     height: 1000px;
     overflow: auto;
  }
}
```